# How to parse html and grab information

Tags: c++, html, html-parsing

Consider this excerpt from an HTML document:

```
<select id="convert-to" name="currency-2">
  <option  value='EUR'>Euro (EUR)</option>
  <option  value='GBP'>British Pound (GBP)</option>
  <option selected='selected' value='USD'>United States Dollar (USD)</option>
  <option  value='AUD'>Australian Dollar (AUD)</option>
  <option  value='CAD'>Canadian Dollar (CAD)</option>
  <option  value='CHF'>Swiss Franc (CHF)</option>
  <option  value='CNY'>Chinese Yuan (CNY)</option>
</select>
```

How do i grab the content like

- Euro (EUR)
- British Pound (GBP)
- United States Dollar (USD)
- Australian Dollar (AUD)

in the above chunk of html code without using any html parser or add-on, just plain C++.

Comment: *without using any html parser* Homework?

Comment: @Oleg2718281828 has a point. Please tag this, if it is homework. Otherwise, I'd suggest to close, because it's not constructive.

Comment: Anyone can help to do it ?? like using pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple approach:

1. Search for the next `"<option"` substring
2. Skip until the next `">"`
3. Read everything until the next `"<"` and store it somewhere
4. Repeat

Comment: it's so much more complicated than this though.  This is one of those wheels it's difficult and dangerous to reinvent

Comment: Well, a real solution would be.  This is a good start for a high school or college C++ intro course though :)  That's gotta be the only reason you'd do it without a real parser.

Comment: @Wug: I agree that it's a bad idea to implement the parsing on your own, but the OP said "in the above chunk of HTML". And in HTML formatted exactly like that it really isn't anymore complicated than how I outlined it.

Comment: well its some sort of extra feature i am implementing in a mini project but in php i can do it easily, but C++ is extremely hard.

Answer (score 2):

> just plainly C++ loop

Impossible. HTML is not regular, therefore it is impossible to use a regular expression to match it.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed this while sanding off other rough spots :)

Comment: hmm is it totally impossible?

Comment: OP didn't mention regular expressions. It's clearly possible to parse HTML in plain C++ due to its Turing-completeness.

Comment: In fact I did one HTML parser in C++ some years ago: it is posible. However I abandoned it because I didn't have time to support new additions.